# How to hide welcome drop down menu from the ribbon in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, ribbon, hide-elements

I am currently working on the masterpage of my sharepoint site and I want to hide the welcome drop down menu that appears on the top right corner of my  sharepoint site and all the tabs. In place of a drop down I only want to display the user's name. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide or remove the welcome control

> < wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
>   style="display:none" >

To add user name without the code use this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2008/06/03/getting-the-current-user-name-or-id-in-sharepoint-using-sharepoint-designer-no-code.aspx?Redirected=true)